# How can I speed up LinkedIn on the client end?

Tags: google-chrome, linkedin, windows

Does anyone know if it's possible to speed up a site, such as LinkedIn, on the client end?

The site is incredibly slow in Chrome, and not much better in Firefox. I've noticed that LinkedIn loads pages more quickly in the Chrome Canary build, which leads me to believe that it is possible to speed things up on my end.

I'm running Chrome on Windows 7 Starter on an Asus Eee, but I get the same slowdown issues in Firefox and also on my Mac. I suspect the true issue is the site itself -- I'm not the only person to complain about the site -- but I'm hoping that there's a band-aid that'll get the site to a usable level of speed.

Comment: Note: Chrome updated itself to version 6 point blah blah today, and LinkedIn is definitely faster, but still on the slow side. The question is less urgent now, but still important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess there's nothing much you can do on the client end specific to a site. Except perhaps ensure that you have enough RAM and processing power free.